# Power BI Report is slow when connected to Big Query on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI service to host my Power BI reports and using Big Query which is on Google Cloud platform as database.

My reports are running quite slow. Whereas the queries when looked in Big query are getting executed in milliseconds but the report in Power BI is taking 10-20 seconds to load. I am having only 2 visuals in the report one table and one slicer and table in the Big query has only 5k rows. And I am using Native Google Big Query Connector for directquery.

Report is taking lot to time to load and slicer change is also very slow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at Query history. It will show what queries Power Bi is running.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey, We have seen that and looks like queries are executing quite fast. mostly in milliseconds. but still report taking long to load and slice